# Is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n+b_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n+\lim_{k \to \infty} b_k)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n),(b_n)$ be convergent sequences.
We know that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n+b_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n+\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n.$$ Is it also true that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n+b_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n+\lim_{k \to \infty} b_k)$$?

Comment: Note that $\lim_{k\to\infty} b_k$ is a constant, so you are simply asking whether $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n+b_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n+C)$, where $C=\lim_{k\to\infty} b_k$.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @durianice But what does that tell us?

Comment: That tells us that your statement is obviously true. For a short proof:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty } a_n+b_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n + \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n + \lim_{k\to\infty} b_k = \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n + C= \lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n+C)=\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n+\lim_{k\to\infty} b_k).
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
    \lim_{n\to \infty}(a_n+b_n)&=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n+\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n\\
    &=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n+\lim_{k\to \infty}b_k\\
    &=\lim_{n\to \infty}(a_n+\lim_{k\to \infty}b_k)
\end{align*}
In the second line, change the name of a dummy variable. The first line you know is justified, and the third is an instance of the same rule with the constant sequence $c_n=\lim_{k\to \infty}b_k$.